# Correctly format URL link in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I have a custom field (called 'website') where a user enters the website to their URL. My php code is as follows

```
<div class="profileInfo">
   <h4  class="website">Website:</h4>
      <?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true)) { ?>
        <p><a href="http://<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true) ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true) ?></a></p>
      <?php } else { ?>
    <p class="na">no email provided</p>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

In the above example I prefix the URL with http://

So my problem is, when a user enters a url like http://www.example.com to the custom field it does not link to the site correctly. The URL looks like this on the frontend http//www.example.com

Strangely the colon : is stripped away or taken out so the URL does not work!I assume this is something to do with having two http://

Now, I have tried removing the http:// from the PHP code liek this

`<p><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true) ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true) ?></a></p>`

So let's say the user now enters www.example.com to the custom field and publishes the entry. The Url now goes to

http://mysite.com/www.example.com

It tries to build the URL into my current site page. No idea why it does not treat it as a URL.

Looking for some help how to correctly write this code in PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php 
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true)) 
{
    $link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'website', true);
    $link = str_replace(array('http://','https://'), array('',''), $link);
    ?><p><a href="http://<?=$link?>"><?=$link?></a></p><?php 
}  
else
{ 
    ?><p class="na">no email provided</p><? 
} 
?>
```

This will replace all http:// in the url.

Comment: hi Scottymeuk, cheers..do u think u can write that in context to my code above? Not sure exactly how to do that

Comment: Hi, thanks again, but I am still struggling to understand how to use this string in relation to my php code provided. Is it possible you can take my snippet above and place your code in it so I can see exactly what I should do? thanks and sorry for the noobiness

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot...appreciate the updates to the code..have to wait 2 more mins before marking right

Comment: No problem at all. Should work, but i hate the text editor on this website, makes writing code so hard.